# Problema de logica no PHP

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho esse banco de dados com uma serie de nomes repetidos com valores na segunda coluna. Oque eu quero fazer e remover as repetições e somar os valores que constam nas pessoas que se repetem

Por exemplo:
[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>clique para visualizar a imagem em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmpi.png)

Porem por algum motivo o calculo não esta sendo feito da forma que deveria (resultado gerado pelo código)
[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>clique para visualizar a imagem em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VQdE.png)

O Código:

```
for($i=1;$i<$linhas;$i++){  
    $a=1;
    if($nome[$i] == $nome[$i+1]){
       $b=0;

       do{
            $b+=$valor[$i];
            $i++;
            $a++;
           
       }while($nome[$i] == $nome[$i+1]);
       
       $tvalor[$i]=$b;
       $tnome[$i] = $nome[$i];
    }else{
        $tvalor[$i] = $valor[$i];
        $tnome[$i] = $nome[$i];
    }

    echo $i . "  " . $tnome[$i] . "  " . $tvalor[$i] . "   " . $a . "   <br>";
}
```

Código PHP completo:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rel1___sheet1 ORDER BY `COL 3` ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i=1;
$linhas=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $nome[$i] = $row["COL 3"];
        $valor[$i] = $row["COL 11"];
        $i++;
        $linhas++;
    }
for($i=1;$i<$linhas;$i++){  
        $a=1;
        if($nome[$i] == $nome[$i+1]){
           $b=0;

           do{
                $b+=$valor[$i];
                $i++;
                $a++;
               
           }while($nome[$i] == $nome[$i+1]);
           
           $tvalor[$i]=$b;
           $tnome[$i] = $nome[$i];
        }else{
            $tvalor[$i] = $valor[$i];
            $tnome[$i] = $nome[$i];
        }

        echo $i . "  " . $tnome[$i] . "  " . $tvalor[$i] . "   " . $a . "   <br>";
    }
}
```

A parte do banco que é consultada:
[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sup>clique para visualizar a imagem em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmKmp.png)

Comment: Ao invés de deixar isso para ser feito no PHP, por que não fazer direto no banco?

Comment: como fazer isso pelo banco?

Comment: Usando a função `SUM` e `GROUP BY`. Por exemplo: `SELECT empresa, SUM(valor) FROM empresas GROUP BY empresa`

Comment: como ficaria essa query? no momento a minha esta assim "SELECT * FROM rel1___sheet1 ORDER BY `COL 3` ASC"(eu importei um csv por isso do nome), no caso os valores que importam estão na COL 3 e na COL 11, que são os nomes e os valores.

Comment: Dá uma editada na sua pergunta e coloca um exemplo do código da consulta mostrando o que/como é retornado

Comment: fiz isso porem o site não interpretou o código corretamente

Comment: Consegue um print do banco?

Comment: o banco foi todo gerado a partir de um csv, então não tem um código para importação

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Faça direto na query:

select nome, sum(valor), count(nome) from tabela
group by nome

acredito que seria mais fácil